# Create this layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, height, drawer

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNbcV.jpg)

I am trying to get this layout. The orange and red are fixed areas. White can be or a listview or a SingleChildScrollView.

This is the Drawer...

So the height of white region is flexible. Orange and red need to be fixed.

I tryed to use Column with mainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly but not worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        Container(color: Colors.orange, height: orangeHeight),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView(),
          ),
        ),
        Container(color: Colors.red, height: redHeight),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: You don't need two columns.  You can do it with one, and three children.

Comment: Works Eric...Thank you Sr.